# How to implement a Spring Rest client

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

Spring contains some nice guide how to setup a simple service for a [pojo/data repository](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-rest/) based on JPA. Unfortunately I can not find the client side implementation or a good example how to access this service via Java itself. In the example there is only shown basic curl access. Maybe I am missing some fundamental basics but in the WEB I only found some basic Rest examples and also a [consuming guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest/) by Spring itself. IMHO these are quite low level, I am looking for a more sophisticated annotation driven implementation possibility.

Comment: Oh, come on, when I'm typing "spring rest client example" in google I'm getting a lot of examples for rest clients.

Comment: @Kamil Sorry for being not explicit enough, I have found some simple examples how to contact and read JSON/Rest resources, however I am looking for a more high level approach. I will adjust my question.

Answer (score 0):

Why not look at `Feign` in the context of `spring-cloud`. It is an declarative Rest client that is originally developed at netflix and has become part of `spring-cloud`. It also nicely integrates some service discovery solutions that are available in the spring-cloud context.

http://projects.spring.io/spring-cloud/spring-cloud.html#spring-cloud-feign

> Feign is a declarative web service client. It makes writing web
>   service clients easier. To use Feign create an interface and annotate
>   it. It has pluggable annotation support including Feign annotations
>   and JAX-RS annotations. Feign also supports pluggable encoders and
>   decoders. Spring Cloud adds support for Spring MVC annotations and for
>   using the same HttpMessageConverters used by default in Spring Web.
>   Spring Cloud integrates Ribbon and Eureka to provide a load balanced
>   http client when using Feign.

A feign client could look like this:

```
@FeignClient("stores")
public interface StoreClient {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/stores")
    List<Store> getStores();

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/stores/{storeId}", consumes = "application/json")
    Store update(@PathVariable("storeId") Long storeId, Store store);
}
```